# Go with for the int without creating an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have the following script:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            String[] s1 = {"red", "white", "black", "blue"};
            String[] s2 = {"red", "black", "green"};
            String[] s3 = {"red", "green"};
            int red = 0;
            int black =0;
            int green = 0;
            int white= 0;
            int blue= 0;

            List <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1));
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2));
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s3));

           for(String s: list)
           {
               if(s.equals("red"))
                {
                   red++;
                }
               else if(s.equals("white"))
                {
                   white++;
                }
               else if(s.equals("black"))
                {
                   black++;
                }
               else if(s.equals("green"))
                {
                   green++;
                }
               else  if(s.equals("blue"))
                {
                   blue++;
                }

           }
            System.out.println(red + "  Red found\n" + green + "  Green Found\n" + white + "  White Found\n" + black + "  Black Found\n" + blue + "  Blue Found");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3  Red found
2  Green Found
1  White Found
2  Black Found
1  Blue Found
```

The problem I have is that I'm adding as int, the need to keep adding to System.out.println, there is some way to go with for the int without creating an Array?

Comment: What are you expecting is not clear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ArrayList Item Counter ie "Apple, 3×Banana, 2×Orange"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498262/java-arraylist-item-counter-ie-apple-3%c3%97banana-2%c3%97orange)

Answer (score 0):

What you need if I understand is a HashMap. You will check if map contains e.g key "red". If it doesn't contain it you insert <"red",0> else you increase the value you found by one
<"red",1>

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String input = "red";
//for each input you will be doing:
if (!map.containsKey(input)) {

    map.put(input,0)
}
else {
    map.put(input,map.get(input)+1);
}
```

Also if you have a single  Collection/ArrayList  I believe you can also do:

```
int redOccurrences = Collections.frequency(colorsList, "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe declare an map of expected colors and use that for counting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> allColorCount;

    //optionally pre-populate your map if you want it to be static colors
    allColorCount.put("blue", 0);
    //... repeat for all colors
    allColorCount.put("white", 0);

    /* 
     * your orig code for populating your lists
     */
     for(String s: list)
     {
        if(allColorCount.containsKey(s))
        {
            allColorCount.put(s, allColorCount.get(s)++);
        }
        //or if you want to dynamically map your counts:
        else
        {
           allColorCount.put(s, 1);
        }
     }

    //then at the end: 
    Set<String> colorSet = allColorCount.keyset();
    for(String currColor : colorSet)
    {
         System.out.println(allColorCount.get(currColor) + " " + currColor + " Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to declase allColorCount as static outside main, otherwise static main() cannot see it as it is a non-static property - edit: you changed your code

Comment: The problem is that in the command: allColorCount.get (s) ++ "s" is a String, so it does not let me add a value.

Comment: You have something wrong.  allColorCount is a hashmap with Integer for its values

Comment: That is what would have to add in * your orig code for populating your lists? I think I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: Look at your previous questions and answers.  You seem to just keep re-posting suggestions without understanding what is happening.